# how to get all record with today's date from firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

my code displays all records, from collection, how i can get record with today's timestamp, i searched for examples from google, but i don't know where to use "where" condition, in my code.

```
Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
 return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
   stream: Firestore.instance.collection('baby').snapshots(),

   builder: (context, snapshot) {
     if (!snapshot.hasData) return LinearProgressIndicator();

     return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.documents);
   },
 );
}

Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
   return Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 200),
     child:ListView(
     children: snapshot.map((data) => listSection(context, data)).toList(),
   )
   );
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
where(Common.DATE_TIME,
              isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day))
```

This is working awesome for me...

Answer (score 0):

For now I don't know if there is a way to do that with the firestore API. But this could be a temporal fix

```
  const oneDay = 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000;
  List filteredList = List();      

     Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
     return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
       stream: Firestore.instance.collection('baby')
            .snapshots(),
       builder: (context, snapshot) {
         if (!snapshot.hasData) return LinearProgressIndicator();

         return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.documents);
       },
     );
    }

    Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot){
      snapshot.forEach((snap){ 
  if((DateTime.now()
    .difference(DateTime.parse(snap.data['timestamp']
    .toDate().toString())))
    .inMilliseconds <= oneDay){
       filteredList.add(snap);
    }
  });

 return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 200),
         child:ListView(
         children: filteredList.map((data) => listSection(context, data)).toList(),
       )
       );
     }
```

Comment: Thanks, i want to get only current date record.

Comment: then it should be: where('timestamp', isEqualTo: DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch)

Comment: what is the value of your timestamp in database

Comment: different dates, eg. December 18,2019 at 11:33:30 PM UTC+3

Answer (score 0):

You can use the client library [cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore) which is is the Dart Client library for firestore.

Using it you can get the data like this:

```
var today = new DateTime.now();
today = new DateTime(today.year, today.month, today.day);
var data = Firestore.instance.collection('talks')
               .where("topic", isGreaterThan: today)
               .snapshots()
```

after this you can use your data to form the widgets as usual

[here](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/where.html) you can see the where syntax with the client library.